# How to inspect the result of an Observable before subscribing to it?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an Angular project which has a service encapsulating http requests like this:

**rest-service.ts**

```
protected post<T>(url: string, data: any = null): Observable<T> {
     return this.http.post<T>(url, data, { withCredentials: true })
        .pipe(this.catchHttpErrors(options)); // method to handle errors
}
```

Then I'd have many other classes using this method:

**example-service.ts**

```
exampleRequest(url: string, data: ExampleData): Observable<ExampleEntity> { 
    this.restService.post<ExampleData>(url, data).subscribe(response => {
         // Handle the logic of the response         
    });     
}
```

As you can see, there's already a method implemented to handle errors in the .pipe() of rest-service.ts.

Imagine I would like to handle certain responses from that request (Eg: If the response returns an empty array or an object {"status": "KO"}) How can I handle it in `rest-service.ts` with another pipe or a RxJs operator instead of adding

```
if(response.status && response.status === 'KO') { // do stuff }
```

to every single class that executes that post request in the subscribe block?

Comment: You can use interceptor in this case. Look for Angular Interceptors

Comment: Yes! It would work indeed but I was wondering how to handle it only using rxjs operators. @mat.hudak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've implemented a "custom" post method in rest-service.ts that wraps the built in http client post call and seemingly handles some error scenarios via `.pipe(this.catchHttpErrors(options))`. Based on your question

> How can I handle it in rest-service.ts with another pipe or a RxJs
> operator instead of adding
>
> if(response.status && response.status === 'KO') { // do stuff }

you could simply add more RxJS operators to that initial pipe call:

```
.pipe(
    this.catchHttpErrors(options),
    filter(response => response.status === 'OK')
)
```

for instance would only return responses with an 'OK' value for the status property.

If you didn't want to modify the base post function you've created, you could create other functions that build upon it. For example:

```
protected postWithLog<T>(url: string, data: any = null): Observable<T> {
    // call your existing post function that returns an observable of T and keep chaining operators to it
    return this.post<T>(url, data) 
        .pipe(tap(responseObject => console.log(responseObject));
}
```

the `.pipe()` function of observables can take many comma separated operators to perform on the value coming through the stream, not just one. Feel free to mix & match as you see appropriate. There are tons of operators built into RxJS that can be chained together in the `.pipe()` method of an observable to achieve pretty much any situation you'd want. Here is a page that lists operators, but many more exist online https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators

Comment: This was the one. I actually implemented it inside the .filter() method. It's not the cleanest way, but I handled it before returning the boolean inside said filter function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interceptor for HTTP requests or instead of use `this.catchHttpErrors` you can pass the error handler to the function from the outside

```
protected post<T>(url: string, data: any = null, errorHandler: Function = null ): Observable<T> 
{
    return this.http.post<T>(url, data, { withCredentials: true })
       .pipe(errorHandler(options)); // method to handle errors
}
```

and then use it like this

`this.restService.post<ExampleData>(url, data, console.log)`